# Limit and Offset not available

Tags: jekyll, swig-template

I'm trying to migrate a web page from jekyll to Swig and I've a problem replicating this part of code:

{% for opt in page.optionals limit: 12 offset: 12 %}

The problem here is that I didn't find the limit and offset filter.
Do you know if there is something similar or if is it possible to create some custom filters?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to create a custom filter.

Here the code

```
swig.setFilter("limit", (input: any, limit, offset) => {
        return input.slice(limit * offset, limit * (offset + 1));
    });
```